# What does the Mad Hatter say to Bayard?

Tags: plot-explanation, alice-in-wonderland-2010

In the film "Alice in Wonderland" (2010), at the Tea party, when Alice is hidden in the teapot Bayard comes sniffing under the table right up to the teapot, indicating that he knows she's in there. The Mad Hatter then says something to him and he goes away. I assume it's some sort of passphrase letting him know that they all work for the white queen.

I couldn't figure out what he says though. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like you assumed: he says "Downal wyth Bluddy Behg Hid!".

It means "Down with the bloody big head" or as the source below quotes it: "Down with the Red Queen, the slogan of the Resistance." ([source](http://www.slashfilm.com/glossary-of-terms-for-tim-burtons-alice-in-wonderland/))

It obviously means that the hatter is hinting Bayard that they are on the same side.

The only thing that might confuse people here is when people assume that Bayard believes in red queen's promises that his family will be released. But I don't think people would still continue to assume the same way after that scene where Bayard helps Alice.

So, as a summary - Bayard knows that he is being used and helps Mad Hatter in this scene leaving Alice.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in [the script](https://8flix.com/assets/unsorted/0-a/Alice-in-Wonderland-2010-by-Linda-Woolverton.pdf). It's a semi-nonsensical phrase used to identify members of the '*Underland Underground Resistance*' to each other.

> **MAD HATTER (cont'd):** *Have you any idea why a raven is like a writing
> desk?*
>
> Hare, Hatter and Dormouse clasp their hands high.
>
> **HATTER/HARE/DORMOUSE:** *Downal wyth Bluddy Behg Hid!*
>
> **ALICE:** *Sorry?*
>
> **CHESHIRE CAT:** ***"Down with the Bloody Big Head". Bloody Big Head being
> the Red Queen.***
>
> **THE DORMOUSE:** ***It's a secret language used by us...the Underland
> Underground Resistance!***

and

> INT. THE TEAPOT - ALICE'S POV
> Alice peeks out the spout. Hare, Hatter and Dormouse sing on despite being hit, choked and dunked.
>
> **HARE/HATTER/DORMOUSE:** *Twinkle Twinkle Twinkle Twinkle!*
>
> The Bloodhound puts its paws on the table, sniffing Alice's teapot. The Hatter takes a chance. He whispers to him.
>
> **MAD HATTER:** ***Downal with Bloody Behg Hid.***
>
> The Bloodhound stops dead. Hatter shoots a look at the teapot. The Bloodhound drops to the ground and sniffs, pretending to catch a new trail.
>
> **KNAVE OF HEARTS:** *Follow the Bloodhound.*